# Encrypted Swapfile Needs Passphrase Every Time I Login

Tags: lubuntu, login, encryption, luks, cryptswap

OS info: Version: Lubuntu 20.04 LTS “Focal Fossa” - Release amd64 (20200423)

How do I stop the OS from asking me to enter the passphrase for the encrypted swapfile every time I login?

I turned a small HP netbook into my first Linux project. Because of its size and limited capability I went with the newest Lubuntu distro. The limited 32GB HDD prompted me to add a 128GB MicroSD. I read about swapfiles and created one (a bit oversized, I’m now learning) and because it’s on the mSD, I encrypted it. Now every time I login I am asked for the passphrase even after checking the remember forever option.

I now know I need to reformat these entire mSD and make this swapfile smaller, but what do I do to stop the passphrase request every time I login and it’s mounted?

Comment: Please specify the actual version of Lubuntu. `cat /var/log/installer/media-info; echo $'\r'` should provide that information.

Comment: Good point. Thanks. 

Version: Lubuntu 20.04 LTS “Focal Fossa” - Release amd64 (20200423)